# Wireshark capture files

Tags: data-request, internet

I am looking for Ethereal / Wireshark / tcpdump captures (`.pcap` or `.pcapng` files) for training purposes. They should cover a wide range of protocols on all OSI layers. Those files would be analyzed by students with Wireshark 2.0.

The captures should be available for free and for commercial use.

Ideally, each of the captures has a problem description and a description on how to find the result.

Answer (score 2):

The Swedish company [NETRESEC AB](http://www.netresec.com) has published a [website with links to PCAP files](http://www.netresec.com/?page=PcapFiles), stating

> This is a list of public packet capture repositories, which are freely available on the Internet.

Unfortunately the term "free" is not defined more precisely.

The captures do not have an exact problem description and analysis, bot they have topics like "cyber defense exercise", "capture the flag competitions" or "malware traffic", which is a good starting point.